# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'seaborn' in Ubuntu

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm running Ubuntu. I have Python and Jupyter notebook installed. When I run `import seaborn as sb` in my Jupyter notebook, it says jupyter `modulenotfound seaborn`. Yet when I try `pip3 install seaborn` in the terminal it says the requirement is already satisfied

I noticed that `which python` shows `/usr/bin/python`, while `which ipython` shows `/usr/local/bin/ipython`

They have to point to the same binary directory, right? How can I do that?

Comment: how are you starting `ipython`

Comment: `jupyter notebook`

Comment: which kernel are you using in jupyter, is it python3 kernel or python kernel

Comment: it says python3

Comment: mind using virtualenv? I generally use virtualenv, its very useful in many ways

Comment: you mean do `python3 -m virtualenv env` and `source env/bin/activate`? Then what after that?

Comment: after that you need to install the required libraries in the activated virtual env. There wont be any problem between python2 and python3, as well as sudo installs

Comment: I already tried `pip3 install seaborn` in the virtual env, but I still get the `ModuleNotFoundError`

Comment: sorry to mention that, in virtualenv you need to install as `pip install seaborn`, `pip install jupyter`, etc. And to run a `.py` file you can use `python filename.py`. It will use the default python version used to create virtualenv, in your case it will be python3.

Comment: Yes, Jupyter has to be installed **and** run in the same `venv`

Comment: that works, thanks. Why is it necessary to run a virtualenv instead of fixing this issue without the virtualenv?

Comment: A virtual environment is a tool that helps to keep dependencies required by different projects separate by creating isolated python virtual environments for them. This is one of the most important tools that most of the Python developers use.

Comment: in the virtualenv, I was able to install seaborn and I thought I had installed sklearn. However, if I try `import sklearn` in the jupyter notebook, I get `ImportError: No module named sklearn`. Yet, if I try Python in the terminal in the virtualenv, and do `import sklearn`, I don't get that error. Why is this?